# External drive seems to work but doesn't respond to Linux tools for repair

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, superblock

I have an external Seagate drive that I'm trying to get to mount by restoring the superblock. The system can see that the disk exists and read the label, but most tools that I run on disk stop performing any task after a few moments and run for hours with no result.

[I've documented what I've tried here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702124/cannot-fsck-or-e2fsck-to-repair-disk-dumpe2fs-returns-couldnt-find-valid-file)

The drive does not seem to be fully dead, but SOMETHING is causing these tools to fail. What could be going on with this drive that could cause tools to fail when they're designed to read damaged drives?

Is there ANY hope for my data?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, there is **some** hope.

Long answer: First, I would make sure it's your drive what is really failing, and not the external USB closure it's in. Try another closure.

Secondly, I had a similar issue some months ago. The drive began to go really slow and some sectors were failing. In this scenario, you should not perfom writing operations in your disk. I would only try to read sector by sector and make an static (maybe partial because of errors) image of the drive in other place.

After you have that image file, you can do fsck operations, mount partitions, or run recovery tools on it. Don't run these operations in the failing disk. It's better to spend its short expected lifetime in really recovering data as is.

In addition, the ideal scenario is recovering data (that is, creating the drive image file) in some snapshot-capable filesystem (BTRFS for example). So you can fsck, recover original, fsck, recover original again and so... or you may face some problems as I did: [Modify a large file, then be able to rollback changes doing it (almost) inplace](https://superuser.com/questions/900370/modify-a-large-file-then-be-able-to-rollback-changes-doing-it-almost-inplace/902025#902025)

Comment: The external is in one of the store bought "MyDisk" style enclosures not meant to be switched out. But this is something I haven't thought of, I'll remove the disk and try a new enclosure. Advice is spot on, thanks for a solid answer.

Comment: You're welcome. But I wouldn't put much hope on this enclosure change to work... It's just an easy and quick first step before going to the long run of data recovering. It took 3 months for me to recover a 500GB disk data. I used `dd`, but you have other tools like `ddrescue` or `ddrescue`. I recovered about 85% of the sectors and all the important data. Don't take it as a general case: it's only my humble personal experience. Good luck!

Comment: My issue is derescue also crashes and won't read. I'm wondering if changing enclosure will allow me to read. If not I'm about at the end of my options.

Comment: Is that always crashing in the same sectors? I had to skip some chunks of data because they showed totally unreadable. That's why I said i recovered about 85% of the sectors. The process I followed: 1) read as much as you can until error 2) on error, try again 3) on error, try again 4) oops, just skip 1MB (for example) and goto 1) again.

Comment: I'll have to look up how to skip sectors. That may help.

Comment: If I'm going to shuck the drive, I'd do a recovery attempt with the drive mounted internally, *much* faster and more reliable. Also, are you using gnu ddrescue? The other one is old and not really maintained.